# AC NPCBots pre-patched repository compilation issue - ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types

Tags: azerothcore

Greeting Gurus!

I have encountered an while trying to compile the AC NPC-Bot pre-patched repository
https://github.com/trickerer/AzerothCore-wotlk-with-NPCBots/

And I have been trying to follow these instructions, https://github.com/trickerer/Trinity-Bots

However the compilation is failing.

As I am using the prepatched repository, I’m attempting to start from 'step 4 (Re) run CMake and (re)build'

To do this, I have run acore.sh and selected options:

- 5. compiler (c): Run compiler tool
- 5. all: clean, configure and compile

However, the compilation seems to fail. This is a link to a text file with the full output for reference https://mega.nz/file/HRJSkYYa#K_1hpeMXINnDWVahk1jtEtE9oC57ozUZHIC7IBfLxyY, however this is the section that appears to be going wrong:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/CoreAI/TotemAI.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_archmage_ai.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_bm_ai.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_dark_ranger_ai.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_death_knight_ai.cpp.o
In file included from /azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_bm_ai.cpp:1:
/azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.h:23:6: fatal error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
enum GossipOptionIcon;
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/build.make:232: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_bm_ai.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_archmage_ai.cpp:1:
/azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.h:23:6: fatal error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
enum GossipOptionIcon;
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/build.make:219: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_archmage_ai.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_dark_ranger_ai.cpp:1:
/azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.h:23:6: fatal error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
enum GossipOptionIcon;
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/build.make:245: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_dark_ranger_ai.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_death_knight_ai.cpp:1:
/azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.h:23:6: fatal error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
enum GossipOptionIcon;
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/build.make:258: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_death_knight_ai.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.cpp:1:
/azerothcore/src/server/game/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.h:23:6: fatal error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
enum GossipOptionIcon;
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/build.make:206: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/AI/NpcBots/bot_ai.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1225: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/Commands/PlayerCommand.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/Commands/cs_arena.cpp.o
```

```
[ 56%] Building CXX object src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/Northrend/IcecrownCitadel/boss_professor_putricide.cpp.o
/azerothcore/src/server/scripts/Northrend/IcecrownCitadel/boss_icecrown_gunship_battle.cpp:1639:21: warning: add explicit braces to avoid dangling else [-Wdangling-else]
                    else if (p->HaveBot())
                    ^
/azerothcore/src/server/scripts/Northrend/IcecrownCitadel/boss_icecrown_gunship_battle.cpp:1897:25: warning: add explicit braces to avoid dangling else [-Wdangling-else]
                        else if (p->HaveBot())
                        ^
2 warnings generated.
[ 56%] Building CXX object src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/Northrend/IcecrownCitadel/boss_sindragosa.cpp.o
```

Ultimately, the compilation then seems to fail before completing:

```
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/World/player_scripts.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/World/server_mail.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/World/world_script_loader.cpp.o
[ 74%] Linking CXX static library libscripts.a
[ 74%] Built target scripts
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2

real    3m25.297s
user    1m9.624s
sys 0m57.404s
acore@4475a2be5105:/azerothcore$
```

I have seen a few articles that recommend adding `-std=c++11` to the compile instructions, but i don’t know where to set that as I’m not a c++ programmer, and am having difficulty tracing through the acore.sh script functions.

I anyone able to help me solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found that the compilation that was performed by the acore.sh dashboard ignored the pre-compiled headers, which was causing the issue.

Instead I followed the manual compilation instructions here: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/linux-core-installation

After that, compilation was successful.

Comment: Please post some more details in your answer